# w2uiのw2formでajaxではないPOSTを実行したい

Tags: javascript

w2uiの[w2form](http://w2ui.realmax.co.jp/docs-142/form-overview-142/)でフォームを作成しています。

w2formではsave()またはsubmit()を実行するとajaxでPOSTが実行されます。

これを、ajaxではなくフォームのsubmitによるPOSTで画面遷移させたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

form要素があれば`$("form").submit()`で行けるのですが、w2formではform要素が存在しない為やり方がわかりませんでした。

```js
var form = $("#form").w2form({
  name: "myForm",
  fields: [
    { name: "user", type: "text" },
    { name: "password", type: "pass"}
  ],
  url: "/test",
  actions: {
    "ログイン": function() {
      //ここでFORMをsubmitして画面遷移したい
      this.submit();
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/w2ui/1.4.3/w2ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/w2ui/1.4.3/w2ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w2formに指定する要素をformに変更してそのformのsubmit()を実行することで出来ました。

※スニペットではエラーになりますが、ローカルにファイルを作成すると実行できます。

```js
var form = $("#form").w2form({
  name: "myForm",
  fields: [
    { name: "user", type: "text" },
    { name: "password", type: "pass"}
  ],
  actions: {
    "ログイン": function() {
      $("#form").submit();
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/w2ui/1.4.3/w2ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/w2ui/1.4.3/w2ui.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/test">
</form>
```